# Cumulative sum in Spark

Tags: sql, scala, apache-spark, hive, cumulative-sum

I want to do cumulative sum in Spark. Here is the register table (input):

```
+---------------+-------------------+----+----+----+
|     product_id|          date_time| ack|val1|val2|
+---------------+-------------------+----+----+----+
|4008607333T.upf|2017-12-13:02:27:01|3-46|  53|  52|
|4008607333T.upf|2017-12-13:02:27:03|3-47|  53|  52|
|4008607333T.upf|2017-12-13:02:27:08|3-46|  53|  52|
|4008607333T.upf|2017-12-13:02:28:01|3-47|  53|  52|
|4008607333T.upf|2017-12-13:02:28:07|3-46|  15|   1|
+---------------+-------------------+----+----+----+
```

Hive query:

```
select *, SUM(val1) over ( Partition by product_id, ack order by date_time rows between unbounded preceding and current row ) val1_sum, SUM(val2) over ( Partition by product_id, ack order by date_time rows between unbounded preceding and current row ) val2_sum from test
```

Output:

```
+---------------+-------------------+----+----+----+-------+--------+
|     product_id|          date_time| ack|val1|val2|val_sum|val2_sum|
+---------------+-------------------+----+----+----+-------+--------+
|4008607333T.upf|2017-12-13:02:27:01|3-46|  53|  52|     53|      52|
|4008607333T.upf|2017-12-13:02:27:08|3-46|  53|  52|    106|     104|
|4008607333T.upf|2017-12-13:02:28:07|3-46|  15|   1|    121|     105|
|4008607333T.upf|2017-12-13:02:27:03|3-47|  53|  52|     53|      52|
|4008607333T.upf|2017-12-13:02:28:01|3-47|  53|  52|    106|     104|
+---------------+-------------------+----+----+----+-------+--------+
```

Using Spark logic, I am getting same above output:

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.expressions.Window
val w = Window.partitionBy('product_id, 'ack).orderBy('date_time)
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._

val newDf = inputDF.withColumn("val_sum", sum('val1) over w).withColumn("val2_sum", sum('val2) over w)
newDf.show
```

However, when I try this logic on spark cluster `val_sum` value will be half of the cumulative sum and something time it is different. I don't know why it is happening on spark cluster. Is it due to partitions?

How I can do cumulative sum of a column on a spark cluster?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

To get the cumulative sum using the DataFrame API you should use the `rowsBetween` window method. In **Spark 2.1 and newer** create the window as follows:

```
val w = Window.partitionBy($"product_id", $"ack")
  .orderBy($"date_time")
  .rowsBetween(Window.unboundedPreceding, Window.currentRow)
```

This will tell Spark to use the values from the beginning of the partition until the current row. Using **older versions** of Spark, use `rowsBetween(Long.MinValue, 0)` for the same effect.

To use the window, use the same method as before:

```
val newDf = inputDF.withColumn("val_sum", sum($"val1").over(w))
  .withColumn("val2_sum", sum($"val2").over(w))
```